# MATLAB Find highest correlation between a set of signals by displacement

Tags: matlab, signals, correlation

Let's assume I have n=10 signals like:

```
  S1  S2  S3  ...
1 1.2 0.6 3.3 ...
2 1.4 0.8 3.5
3 1.6 1.0 3.3
4 1.4 1.2 3.1
5 2.2 1.0 2.9 ...
.
.
```

Now I want to find the maximum correlation of these signals by shifting them. I tried to write a code myself which is looking for the highest correlation. But I did not succeed. I also tried to use the function `xcorr`. But here I can only work with two vectors of numbers (signals).

Is there a better way to displace the signals in a way to get the highest correlation between them? Furthermore I want to plot them afterwards. For signals with only one peak I should get a plot where all maximums are at the same position in order to get the highest correlation.

Comment: I think `xcorr` is a good idea. But there are two ways to go. You can shift the signals in a way that every signal has to every other signal the highest possible correlation. Here you would need some sort of an optimizer. Or you can take one signal as reference (e.g. S1) and shift every other signal, so it reaches the maximum correlation with S1. The second way is far simpler than the first and can be done with `xcorr`.  In [xcorr](http://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) is also an example how to do the plotting. So which way is your favorite?

Comment: Maybe you also can adapt [beamforming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamforming) in some way...